# Open two separate apps alternately?

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible in Python Kivy to switch back and forth between two different apps via respectively clicking a button?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Schließen und Zweite App starten')
        button.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_second_app)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def switch_to_second_app(self, instance):
        self.stop()  # Schließt die erste App
        SecondApp().run()  # Startet die zweite App


class SecondApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Zurück zur Ersten App')
        button.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_first_app)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def switch_to_first_app(self, instance):
        self.stop()  # Schließt die zweite App
        FirstApp().run()  # Startet die erste App


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstApp().run()
```

That works on computer, but it doesn't work that way on an android device, because you probably can't reopen an app directly in the same main loop(?). Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you are writing both apps, you can just combine them into one app.

Comment: No, I would like to open them separately because I'm trying to receive GPS data continuously on my own phone. One is in icon size and runs in the background. The other one is in fullscreen.

Comment: Can't you just run whatever your background app does in another thread or subprocess of the main app?

Comment: No. I would like to permanently and automatically determine my working hours with my personal mobile device via GPS. But as soon as I close the app, my location permission is ALWAYS revoked for data protection reasons, so no more GPS. As far as I know, this can't be prevented :(  So now I'm trying not to close the app but to switch from full screen to icon size so I don't have to close it.